# Rails 6 ActionText. Can a form use multiple rich text fields?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-6, trix, actiontext

I'm using multiple rich text fields in my form on a rails 6 app, but only the first field is storing in the database the remaining fields are not showing on the db at all .

**module.rb**
`has_rich_text :content` 
`has_rich_text :references` 
`has_rich_text :footnotes`
**_form.html.erb**
f.rich_text_area :content
f.rich_text_area :references
f.rich_text_area :footnotes
**controller.rb** 
params.require... :content, :references, :footnotes...

Answer (score 2):

You need to override the input's `id` attribute, like so:

`<%= form.rich_text_area :footnotes, class: "", id: "modelname_#{form_model.id}_footnotes" %>`, where the id is an arbitrary string that must be unique, like "chapter_1_footnotes".

Answer (score 0):

Yes this can work but make sure the names of your has_rich_text :attribute_name doesn't  match any of the attribute names on your model.